# How do I go about repeating an automated test many times without having to copy it many times and run it in a suite?

Tags: repeat

I currently have to create an automated test many times and run them in a suite.  But I was just wondering if there was a way of simply repeating a single version of an automated test many times without having to make many copies of the same test.

Creating many versions of the same test and running them together in a suite. But this can get quite long winded if you want to run many test many times.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, I am working with Selenium IDE

Comment: You can edit your question by click on the edit link underneath your question. Also add the tag selenium to your question .